# Cordova Camera Plugin, saveToPhotoAlbum option is not working in Android 5.0.1

Tags: android, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I want to save the picture in album after capturing the picture using Cordova Camera Plugin.

So I tried with the camera option 'saveToPhotoAlbum' set to true, but this is not saving the captured image but the same is working in iOS.

I set the following options:

```
{ quality : 50,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  targetWidth: 1000,
  targetHeight: 1000,
  correctOrientation: true,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem by changing the `destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`

Comment: How can I access to the taken photo later? I mean when I close app, I want to access the url or location of image and save the path in localStorage or local database and use later.

Comment: You can use the Cordova File plugin to read the image from the device and use it.

Comment: But it doesn't save the picture in the gallery, it just saves it in cache file. While I use this: `saveToPhotoAlbum: true`

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens due to update of camera plugin. If you have not updated your cordova version then updating it will resolve that issue or you can just downgrade the camera plugin version to 0.3.5

For downgrading camera version simply fire below commands:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera
```

and then

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera@0.3.5
```

I am sure that it will resolve your issue.